# QgsDistanceArea.convertMeasurement not enough arguments error

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, distance, measurements

I have setup a custom processing/python script to determine the shortest path on a network based on the code for Dijkstra's algorithm here,

http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/network_analysis.html#id4

Similar to the Road Graph plugin, I want to obtain the distance of the path as well. I've setup my code as below but I keep getting errors for the convertMeasurement function.

```
QgsDistanceArea.convertMeasurement(float, QGis.UnitType, QGis.UnitType, bool) 
-> (float, QGis.UnitType): not enough arguments See log for more details
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've been researching and googling this problem but can't seem to find a solution. I've included some commented out lines of code as well to show what other options I've tried.

```
distance_measure = QgsDistanceArea()
distance_measure.setSourceCrs(crs)
distance_measure.setEllipsoidalMode(True)
#distance_measure.setEllipsoid('GDA94')
dist_unit = QGis.UnitType()
dist_unit_deg = QGis.UnitType(2)
#dist_unit
print dist_unit
print dist_unit_deg
#print type(dist_unit)
#QgsDistanceArea.convertLengthMeasurement(distance_measure, dist_unit)

dist_val = distance_measure.measureLength(rb.asGeometry())
print dist_val
QgsDistanceArea.convertMeasurement(distance_measure, dist_unit_deg, dist_unit, False)
print distance_measure.lengthUnits()
#print QgsDistanceArea.formatDistance(dist_val,QGis.Meters,5)
```

Comment: QgsDistanceArea.convertMeasurement isn't a static method. Try distance_measure.convertMeasurement(...)

Comment: The procedure for measuring length is not so complicated. Please, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the way, the ellipsoid of 'GDA94' SRS is 'GRS80' so, you can use next code to calculate distances for one line type geometry.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

feat = layer.getFeatures().next()
geom = feat.geometry()

distance_measure = QgsDistanceArea()

distance_measure.setEllipsoid('GRS80')

distance_measure.setEllipsoidalMode(True)

print distance_measure.measureLength(geom)
```

To test my code, I used line shapefile (EPSG:4283 = GDA94) of next image:

[image]

After running the code, the length of this line was printed at the Python Console of QGIS: 1087287.01705 m (1087.28701705 km). When 'Measure Line Tool' is used, it is also visualized (see next image) that results are comparable. This code works.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @xunilk!! Worked! I'm new to GIS so getting my head around working with CRSs etc. Is there a good reference you would know especially for programmers? Do the unit measurements change according to the CRS set?

Comment: You're welcome. You can use: http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/pdf/en/QGIS-2.2-PyQGISDeveloperCookbook-en.pdf. In relation to last question, with **QgsDistanceArea**, you set the ellipsoid of CRS; where this should be in degrees. If you work with a projection in meters (or feet) you can use **QgsGeometry** class instead of **QgsDistanceArea**.